# Include Authorization Permissions to my token using Keycloak Mapper

Tags: redhat, keycloak, keycloak-services

I would like Keycloak (2.3.0.Final) to include the permissions associated to user in the ID token. I tried to create a mapper to map the all permissions, but unfortunatelly, there is no option to add this kind of feature.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a friend, I solved this!

The problem is, I'd like to retrieve information about authorization that belongs to a specific client. In the current version of Keycloak (2.3.0.Final) You are not able to retrieve permissions through the token, and this is make totally sense.

So you have 2 alternatives: first one is using [permission ticket](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/authorization-services-guide/content/topics/overview/terminology.html#_permission_ticket), and another one is by Entitlement API.

So, I'm using the second alternative:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
    "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm_name}/authz/entitlement/${resource_server_id}"
```

which is **realm_name**, is the name that was added to realm (presented in url), and **resource_server_id**, is the client_id that was chosen in client settings.

Also, the first alternative will be used with a [permission ticket](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/authorization-services-guide/content/topics/overview/terminology.html#_permission_ticket):

```
curl -X POST
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AAT}" -d '{
    "ticket" : ${PERMISSION_TICKET}
}' "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm_name}/authz/authorize"
```

Here is some useful links to solve this:

- [authorization services](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/authorization-services-guide/content/topics/service/overview.html)
- [Requesting Entitlements](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/authorization-services-guide/content/topics/service/entitlement/entitlement-api-aapi.html)